# Why do i get extra animations in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, fbx

So i created a model animation in Blender. Most of the objects in Blender have their own animation.
when i export the file to FBX and then import it to Unity, there are lot of extra animation files. like for each object there are about 8 animations, and they doesn't seem to do anything either. Only one works as it should. what is happening with me?[As you can see in the image, there are lot of animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKWFM.png)

Comment: What isn't working as it should and as for your animations it looks like you may have multiple objects that are being used within blender. This being that you have not combined all of the objects or merged the objects. This would cause blender to export all of the different objects separately thus the additional files for the 8 animations.

Comment: You have these animations inside blender. Look your Action animations inside Blender and google it how to get rid of them. I think it is not Unity related.